# R.id not recognizing xml id's

Tags: java, android, xml, r.java-file

I'm new to android and trying to create a basic four function calculator. I have two input boxes for the two numbers with the id's number1 and number2. When I try to use R.id.number1 it does not recognize the id. How can I fix this?

Comment: you should edit your question and post some layout xml

Answer (score 2):

it because you didn't build your project automatically. just click your project, and click "clean" on "project" menu or you can click "bulid automatically" on your "project" menu.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the ids on the 2 input boxes are @+id/number1 and @+id/number2 not just number1 and number2.